# Accessing Ubuntu from Windows over Samba: The specified network name is no longer available

Tags: windows, samba, file-sharing

I've just installed Samba on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine and need to access it from Windows Server 2008.

```
$ sudo apt-get install samba
$ service smbd status
smbd start/running, process 23485
```

When I try to connect from the Windows *Run* dialog using `\\192.168.1.111` (verified using `ifconfig`) I see the error message:

> \\192.168.1.111
>
> The specified network name is no longer available

This error pops up immediately. Note that before installing `smbd` the error took a while to appear and was a generic *cannot connect to host* type error. If I stop `smbd`, then the response goes back to timing out, so I know there's connectivity between the boxes.

What does this mean and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I've worked around this for now by having Ubuntu connect to a share on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

when you map the network drive from Windows, do not [Browse] for the share. instead, type it in manually (eg. \192.168.0.100\ubuntushare). then check the box that says, "Connect using different credentials".

when you click [Finish], you'll be prompted for a network password.  enter either your Ubuntu login credentials (or, preferably, your samba user/pass (as generated with the command: sudo smbpasswd -a USERNAME)).